# What is the fate of the Asgardians at the start of Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, asgardians

*Thor: Ragnarok* ends with the remaining people of Asgard aboard a refugee ship that meets Thanos' ship. *Avengers: Infinity War* opens with

> Thanos and his minions having commandeered the ship and several bodies can be seen on the floor.

This begs the question, what happened to these characters:

- Korg
- Miek
- Asguardian extra #3
- Valkyrie

Comment: Given the names are pretty well known for anyone watching Thor: Ragnarok, I don't see why that should be hidden behind spoiler tags. Also, please try to use the universe tag before any additional tags you might add, properly catalogued questions help keep the site clean. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been confirmed upon in *Avengers: Endgame*, in short the Asgardians, presumably half of them, escaped to Earth and created "New Asgard". Of the half of the Asgardians that survived the named characters we see are:

> 1. Valkyrie, essentially appears to be leading the people whilst Thor drinks himself away in "isolation". At the end of the film she is made Queen of Asgard by Thor for her natural leadership.
>  
>  2. Korg, appears to be living with Thor playing Fortnite and generally not doing much.
>  
>  3. Miek, again appears to be living with Thor and probably doing even less.

Comment: new asgard was established in Tonsberg, Norway what is the reason that they chose this specific place

Comment: @codeczar that sounds like a new question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia they already [asked it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/214501/58193).

Answer (score 15):

From [this article](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/01/avengers-infinity-war-valkyrie-asgardian-fate/) referencing [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8g10pg/joe_russo_came_and_had_a_qa_at_our_high_school/) (emphasis mine):

> According to the Redditor, **Russo confirmed Valkyrie did survive Thanos’ ambush**. The director did not say how, but he did say **a portion of the Asgardians also survived. Russo said escape pods ferried those survivors away from the battle**, giving the Asgardian race the chance to escape extinction. It is very possible the Valkyrie was charged with overseeing that evacuation since most of the Asgardian refugees were simple civilians.
>
> And, if you are curious about Korg, then prepare to be a bit let down. The Redditor said they asked Russo whether the fan-favorite character made it out of the ambush alive. **The director said he wasn’t “willing” to reveal Korg’s fate just yet**, so fans will have to keep their fingers crossed for the hero a little while longer.

Long story short:

- the ship had escape pods, so some Asgardians survived.
- Valkyrie survived
- Korg's fate is as yet unrevealed.

Comment: Pure speculation: Miek's dead. Thanos accidentally stepped on him.

Comment: Further speculation: Miek's alive! And Korg's really sorry for not helping much against Thanos, but he didn't have time to print even *one* pamphlet encouraging everyone to resist.

Answer (score 9):

At one point during *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thor says that half of his people are dead (which makes sense since that's Thanos' whole m/o).

> **Thor:** Thanos already has the Power Stone because he stole it last week, when he decimated Xandar. He stole the Space Stone from me **when he destroyed my ship and slaughtered half my people.** The Time and Mind Stones are safe on Earth. They're with the Avengers.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

However, the only people that we see die/dead are Loki and Heimdall.

It is unknown at this point the fate of any other specific Asguardians.

Comment: Re-watching the film I also caught the cc and introduction to that scene. There was an Asgardian that calls out over the radio asking for help, saying that they are not a military vessel, and also that the craft they are on is called the Statesman. I do not remember a name given to the craft that Loki rescued everybody with, but my current thought is that the "half that survived" are on a different ship called the Statesman.

Answer (score 2):

Valkyrie survived both Thanos' attack on the Asgardian ship as well as his "*Snap*", according to the actor who portrayed her, Tessa Thompson.

> **Q.** Did Valkyrie disintegrate?
>
> **A.** *No, she’s in one piece and THRIVING*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/TessaThompson_x/status/1045943643574546433): Edited for legibility</sup></sub>

Comment: Well, is this actor empowered to make that statement?   I doubt it.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - What makes you think she isn't?

Comment: She has a vested interest in the character appearing in future films.   It doesn't necessarily make it so.   And it doesn't mean that until such a time as it happens, it isn't open to being changed on a whim as the needs of story and production and actor negotiations dictate.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - This is a multi-billion-dollar franchise. What makes you think that she's even allowed to say anything about her character without getting nineteen people from Marvel to clear it first?

Comment: Because it's been shown time and time again that this isn't usually how Twitter works?   She may have some kind of agreement about what she can talk about, but I seriously doubt every tweet is being reviewed by over a dozen people.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Having seen the damage a tweet (or two) can wreak on a franchise, I'd be astounded if these actors aren't closely monitored. And if they aren't, then they bloody well should be

Answer (score -4):

At the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War*, we see the Asgardian's refugee ship filled with

> the bodies of the survivors of *Thor: Ragnarok*. The children of Thanos can be seen going around stabbing the bodies, implying that not all of them have died. Thor, Loki, Hulk, and Heimdall all are still alive, but are incapacitated to some extent (Heimdall in particular is lying wounded on the floor). It's clear that **the attack on the refugee ship by Thanos has left nearly everyone who stood in his way dead or incapacitated.**

Further on we see the refugee ship completely destroyed, leaving Thor floating in space to be rescued later by the Guardians of the Galaxy. When Thor is finally rescued, he makes no plea to his rescuers to search the area for survivors. Therefor, Thor must either not care for the others aboard the ship or must have known he was the only one who could have survived the destruction of the ship and the subsequent float through the vacuum of space.

So to answer your question:

> **The Asgardians aboard the ship are dead**. **Korg and Miek are most likely dead too**, unless they left the ship through some other means before the attack.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. Half of the Asgardians survived, according to the filmmakers