# Why did Thor lie to the Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Thor first talks to the Guardians, he told them that Thanos killed half the people on his ship. Untrue. He killed everyone except Thor. Nobody was moving except for Thor and Loki, and then Loki got killed. Thanos then blew up the ship. Nobody was alive on that ship except Thor. Only Thor got picked up. Um, what? What motivation is there to lie?

Comment: TL;DR: He didn't lie, some did survive

Comment: Who said everyone was dead? We only *saw* a few dead....there's no reason the others couldn't be alive. Also, as I recall, half of the Asgardians got away from the attack

Comment: https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-asgardians-survived/

Comment: It's also answered in our sister site: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88487/are-there-any-more-asgardians

Comment: The Directors have confirmed that half the Asgardians where allowed to escape, this is after all how Thanos works, he destroys 50% of what he comes across.

Comment: I'm just going to stop asking questions, because people always seem to downvote my questions so much I can't even comment. I just wanted an answer to something I didn't know about.

Answer (score 7):

## He doesn't lie

We see that in this very related question: [What is the fate of the Asgardians at the start of Avengers: Infinity War?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186707/58193)

> From [this article](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/05/01/avengers-infinity-war-valkyrie-asgardian-fate/) referencing [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8g10pg/joe_russo_came_and_had_a_qa_at_our_high_school/) (emphasis mine):
>
> > According to the Redditor, **Russo confirmed Valkyrie did survive Thanos’ ambush**. The director did not say how, but he did say **a portion of the Asgardians also survived. Russo said escape pods ferried those survivors away from the battle**, giving the Asgardian race the chance to escape extinction. It is very possible the Valkyrie was charged with overseeing that evacuation since most of the Asgardian refugees were simple civilians.

As some Asgardians beside Thor survived we can see that Thor does not lie.

Comment: @Com10burnsaway I think I’ve seen a post where someone spots some in the background but yeah it’s from an interview with the directors rather than mostly visual evidence.